# Do I need root (admin) permissions to run userspace 'perf' tool? (perf events are enabled in Linux kernel)

Tags: linux, kernel, non-root-user, perf-event

Do I need to have to run `perf` userspace tool as system administrator (root), or can I run it (or at least some subcommands) as an ordinary user?

Comment: Unix programs that can't do what they need to do for lack of permissions will usually thrown an error if they can't do their job. Run it and see!

Comment: I am asking this question to decide whether it is worth trying to install (as ordinary user, in $HOME) userspace part of **`perf`** tool (which is/can be non-trivial).

Comment: FYI in Ubuntu **`perf`** is in `linux-tools` package, so installing `perf` there is simple.

Comment: @JakubNarębski: Except if it is not your own machine and the admins are reluctant to install packages.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

What you can do with `perf` without being root depends on the [`kernel.perf_event_paranoid`](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/sysctl/kernel.txt) [sysctl setting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sysctl).

- `kernel.perf_event_paranoid` = 2: you can't take any measurements. The `perf` utility might still be useful to analyse existing records with `perf ls`, `perf report`, `perf timechart` or `perf trace`.
- `kernel.perf_event_paranoid` = 1: you can trace a command with `perf stat` or `perf record`, and get kernel profiling data.
- `kernel.perf_event_paranoid` = 0: you can trace a command with `perf stat` or `perf record`, and get CPU event data.
- `kernel.perf_event_paranoid` = -1: you get raw access to kernel tracepoints (specifically, you can `mmap` the file created by [`perf_event_open`](http://lxr.linux.no/#linux+v2.6.39/kernel/perf_event.c#L6420), I don't know what the implications are).

Comment: Nice.  `cat /proc/sys/kernel/perf_event_paranoid` returns 1, so it seems that I would be able to take at least some measurements (BTW. whats the difference betwen "kernel profiling data" and "CPU event data"?  Reference is enough)

Comment: @Jakub: From what I understand, kernel events let you see calls to various kernel functions. CPU events are counters in the CPU that tell you how many times a particular location in memory was hit. I've never used them, so I can't tell you more about them; [LWN](http://www.google.com/search?q=perf-event+site:lwn.net) has quite a few article on the topic, and it's still evolving.

Comment: With paranoid=2, you can still profile your own code in user-space (e.g. `perf stat awk 'BEGIN{for(i=0;i<10000000;i++){}}'` will show accurate user-space cycle and instruction counts, and you can even get counts for `uops_issued.any`  and so on), but you don't get counts for code that ran during system calls/interrupts.  So the reported CPU frequency (cycles / time) is at least slightly lower than actual because of time spent in kernel.  See also [What restriction is perf\_event\_paranoid == 1 actually putting on x86 perf?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51911368)

Comment: "CPU events" means profiling everything on a whole core, instead of per-process / thread.  i.e. paranoid=1 or higher stops you from profiling other user's code, and 1 only lets you profile kernel code invoked by your own processes (system calls.)

Answer (score -1):

These are the steps I needed to take to allow perf to record events on RHEL8:

```shell
sudo mount -o remount,mode=755 /sys/kernel/tracing/
sudo sh -c 'echo -1 >/proc/sys/kernel/perf_event_paranoid'
sudo sh -c 'echo 0 >/proc/sys/kernel/kptr_restrict'
```

After that I could run perf as a regular user:

```shellsession
~$ perf record -e block:block_rq_complete -ag sleep 5
[ perf record: Woken up 1 times to write data ]
[ perf record: Captured and wrote 0.045 MB perf data ]
```